# phoneGap change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm not very good in english and in phonegap :p
I have a home page with a list I want to go to another page when I touch an li.
I tryed `<a href="otherpage.html">` and `<a href="#otherpage.html">` and `<a href="#otherpage">`

my code :

```
<ul style="padding:20px;">
  <li style="background-image:url(logo.jpg)">
        <a href="#aaa.html">hi</a>.
  </li>
  </ul>
```

sorry if that not very clear in english and thanks.

Comment: and what is it doing when you click?  Does it work in the browser?

Comment: doing nothing same if i click on the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-android.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

function init(){  
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", console.log('ready'), true);
}


</script>  

  </head>
  <body onload="init();">

    <ul>
    <li><a href="second.html">hi</a>.</li>
    </ul>


  </body>
</html>
```

try like this...

Comment: hey you can use changePage method of jquery mobile for that..                for example : $.mobile.changePage( "second.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });

Comment: hmm that interesting but i put that in for exemple 
<span onclick="$.mobile.changePage( "second.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });"> sencond </span> ?

Answer (score 3):

```
 <ul style="padding:20px;">
  <li style="background-color:yellow">
      <span onclick='$.mobile.changePage( "http://www.google.com", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: true });'>hi</span>.
  </li>
  </ul>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n9BK4/)